# jQuery iterate through table cells and add hour from loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code which loops through hours 0600-2300. Basically, I want to take the hours and add them to a table cell attribute. There are multiple `td.daterow` rows, each with columns for hours 0600-2300.

```
for (var h = 6; h < 24; h++)
{
  $( "td.daterow" ).each(function() {
     $(this).attr("data-hour", h);
  });
}
```

But this code doesn't loop through the hours like I'd like. Instead of having cells with attributes 0600-2300, it just adds "23" to each `data-hour`. How can I loop through the hours and add them accordingly?

============================

Also, I'm not sure how complicated this would be to add. If each cell is split into two cells to accommodate for the 30 minute interval (so 36 columns total). Would it possible to include whole hours as well as their respected 30 minute interval with the loop (if that makes sense)?

Comment: Do you already have the correct amount of table cells (18)?

Comment: Yes, there are 18 table cells (columns).

Comment: Is the missing '00' after each hour part of your problem, or should the answers only address the problem of them all being 23?

Comment: Easy to extend, double the cycle to 36 in my solution, in the statement add different treatments for odd or even indices. Half the index for the hour calculation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the correct amount of table cells already exist, the problem is simply that for each hour value, you are looping over each table cell and setting it. Naturally, each hour value will overwrite the previous ones.

To fix this, remove your outer loop and use the index of the td element to determine the hour.

```
$( "td.daterow" ).each(function(index) {
    var hour = index + 6;
     (this).attr("data-hour", hour);
  });
```

Comment: Your solution works...sort of. If I have multiple rows of `td.daterow`, the next row will start at 25. I tried adding `if(index > 24) index = 0;` but that didn't seem to solve it.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure how complicated this would be to add. If each cell is split into two cells to accommodate for the 30 minute interval (so 36 columns total). Would it possible to include whole hours as well as their respected 30 minute interval with the loop (if that makes sense)?

Comment: @Spencer, by *multiple rows*, do you mean more than 18? What do you want to happen in this case? Do you want the extra rows to be set to 6? Do you want to not set the attribute value at all for them?

Comment: by multiple rows, I mean a whole new table row with 18 new cells.

Comment: @Spencer, I think this is more suitable as a second question rather than a comments discussion. It depends on how you structure your table. If your table is structured so that it has one row for each hour, with two cells for each row, you could do something similar to the code in my answer. You could iterate over each table row, using the index to determine the hour. Then for each row, the first cell could contain the hour, and the second could contain the hour + 30 minutes.

Comment: @Spencer, if you have multiple 18 row tables and want to do the same thing for each of them, there are a couple of ways you could do this. The simplest is to just change the definition of hour to be index % 18 + 6. A more involved option is to use jQuery to select all of the tables you want, and for each table, do the above loop to populate the data. To get all of the rows of a table, use jQuery's find function.

Answer (score 2):

You need to walk through your loop more carefully. Each iteration you are executing `$(this).attr("data-hour", h)` on **all** of the `td.daterow` elements.

So in the first iteration, `h=6` and you set each `data-hour` to 6. In the second iteration, `h=7`, and you now overwrite each `data-hour` attribute with 7. As we loop, this continues until each `data-hour` is 23, at which point `h=24` and the loop terminates.

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do, but I think you want to set each `data-hour` to a successively higher value (or hour). You could do something like this:

```
var arr = $("td.daterow");
for (var h = 6; h < 24; h++) {
    $(arr[h-6]).attr("data-hour", h);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You perform two nested loops, the for and the each() loop with fixed h.

This might work (sorry I am on iPad now, can not test :-)

```
$.each($("td.daterow"), function(idx, ele) {
  var h = 6 + (idx % 18);
  ele.attr("data-hour", h);
});
```

Extended version:

```
$.each($("td.daterow"), function(idx, ele) {
  var i = idx % 36;
  if (i % 2 == 0) {
    var h = 6 + (i / 2);
    ele.attr("data-hour", h);
  } else {
    var h = 6 + ((i-1)/2);
    ele.attr( /* half hour treatment based on h */);
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var h = 6;
$( "td.daterow" ).each(function() {
  if(h<24 && h>=6) {
    $(this).attr("data-hour", h + "00");
    h++;
  }
});
```

Comment: The if condition is not met because h is not greater than 6.